# WP_enqueue_script inside shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I've got shortcode that needs to include JS library only once and only there where it's used.

```
function shortcode_function($atts, $content = null) {
    $class = shortcode_atts( array('something' => '0'), $atts );

    return "<script src=\"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\"></script> 
            And here goes HTML code for the map.";
}
add_shortcode("sh", "shortcode_function");
```

The problem is that above example is going to include library several times if maps shortcode is used several times. How can I prevent that? Or more precisely: how can I do it "the correct way"? Can I use `wp_enqueue_script()` in that place?

Just one requirement: I really need this to include that library **only-when-shortcode-is-used**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use `wp_enqueue_script()`. The script will be loaded in the footer (action: `wp_footer()`). Just once.

To inspect the order of available hooks, functions etc. per request try my plugin [T5 WP Load Order](https://gist.github.com/4055044).

Comment: So, `add_shortcode` is aware of this and it's not too early or too late to register and enqueue this?

Comment: The shortcode itself is “script agnostic”. :) You can enqueue scripts any time before `wp_footer()` was called, be it in a shortcode or somewhere else. [Example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40063/73).

Comment: Thanks for that link. It mentions EXACT code that I'm looking for :) It looks like it has been introduced in WP3.3, so just a few months ago. It's hard to tell when it's not too late to run something in WP and when it's already too late (like all these hooks) - I haven't found any debugging method for that, yet, so that's why I asked if it's surely "the correct" way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul See my update for a plugin to inspect the load order.

Comment: Thanks :) I will surely try this. It's hard to get to know what WordPress actually does and in what order (and it's not well documented anywhere). Especially WP Query, hooks and actions should have better explanation somewhere. Filters and something like "walker" are unknown subjects for me, too (to use these you often need to know what actually happens as default action and there is no easy way to just print that in variable). Scripts like in your link are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We can indeed conditionally load CSS and JS files via shortcode conditionally, when the  shortcode is present and without using any *overly elaborate* functions:

Refer to comment #348349 here: [Enqueue Scripts / Styles when shortcode is present](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present/348349#348349)